# reusing auto-complete input field in different forms using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosuggest

I have two different forms "#form1" and "#form2".. Both the forms has a input field where respective suggested options will be shown taking the keyword as an input. They have same names, and ajax function will call same php file to retrieve data.

forms are like

form1:-

```
form2:-
<form id="#form2">
```

auto-complete script is like

```
var mainHolder   = ".tag_holder";
var inputBox     = ".sharing_with";
var ajaxFilePath = "http://localhost/corridor/index.php/posts/search_to_tag_frnds";

var ajax_response = ".ajax_response";
var ids = new Array();

// initialization's
$("<div class='ajax_response'></div>").insertAfter(inputBox);
$(mainHolder).addClass("fb_holder");
$(mainHolder).val("").focus();


// on focus of textbox show list

$(inputBox).keyup(function(event){
    var p = $(mainHolder);
    var offset = p.offset();

    // create ajax request and get all the friend names starting with name XXX
    var keyword = $(inputBox).val();
    var selected = ids;
    //var selected = $("#selected_ids").val();
    //var theArray = selected.split(", ");

    // remove select-friend class
    //$(mainHolder).find(".selected-friend").removeClass("selected-friend");
    //$(mainHolder).find(".selected-friend").find("#rmv_tag").css("color","#8F8F8F");

    if(keyword.length)
     {
         if(event.keyCode != 40 && event.keyCode != 38 && event.keyCode != 13)
         {
            // $(ajax_response).css("left",parseInt(offset.left));
            // $(ajax_response).css("top",parseInt(offset.top + $(mainHolder).height()));
             $(ajax_response).css("z-index","1040");
             $(ajax_response).css("width",parseInt($(mainHolder).width()/2));

             if(ajaxFilePath != "")
             {
                 $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://localhost/corridor/index.php/posts/search_to_tag_frnds?added_ids[]="+ids,
                   data: "data="+keyword,
                   success: function(rep){  
                    if(rep != 0)
                      $(ajax_response).html(rep).css("display","block");
                    else
                      $(".list").css("display","none");
                   }
                 });
             }
         }
         else
         {
            $("li .selected").removeClass("selected");
            switch (event.keyCode)
            {
             case 40:
             {
                  found = 0;
                  $(".list li").each(function(){
                     if($(this).attr("class") == "selected")
                        found = 1;
                  });
                  if(found == 1)
                  {
                    var sel = $("li[class='selected']");
                    // check if his is a last element in the list
                    // if so then add selected class to the first element in the list
                    if(sel.next().text() == "")                 
                        $(".list li:first").addClass("selected");
                    else
                        sel.next().addClass("selected");
                    // remove class selected from previous item
                    sel.removeClass("selected");
                  }
                  else
                    $(".list li:first").addClass("selected");
                 }
             break;
             case 38:
             {
                  found = 0;
                  $(".list li").each(function(){
                     if($(this).attr("class") == "selected")
                        found = 1;
                  });
                  if(found == 1)
                  {
                    var sel = $("li[class='selected']");
                    // check if his is a last element in the list
                    // if so then add selected class to the first element in the list
                    if(sel.prev().text() == "")                 
                        $(".list li:last").addClass("selected");
                    else
                        sel.prev().addClass("selected");
                    // remove class selected from previous item
                    sel.removeClass("selected");
                  }
                  else
                    $(".list li:last").addClass("selected");
             }
             break;
             case 13:

                $(ajax_response).css("display","none");
                var value = $("li[class='selected']").find("a").attr("value");
                addFriend($("li[class='selected']").text(),value);
             break;
            }
         }
     }
    else
        $(ajax_response).fadeOut("slow");
});
// on click of list item mark that friend as selected

$("#rmv_tag").live("click",function(){
    var found = "";
    // remove selected friend
    $(this).parent().css("display","none");
    // get id of selected item
    var index = $(this).parent(".added").attr("id");
    // find items index in ids array
    for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        if(ids[i] == index){
            found = i;
            continue;
        }
    }
    // remove selected index
    if(index != " " || index != "undefined")
        ids.splice(parseInt(found),1);
    // print updated ids
    $("#selected_ids").val(ids);
});


$(inputBox).focus(function(){
    // remove class
    $(mainHolder).find(".selected-friend").removeClass("selected-friend");
    $(mainHolder).find("#rmv_tag").css("color","#6abf88");
});
$(".list li").live("mouseover",function () {
      $("li[class='selected']").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
});
$(".list li").live("mouseout",function () {
      $("li .selected").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
$(".add_tag").live("click",function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var id = $(this).find("a").attr("value");
    // mark friend as selected and add to selected ist
    addFriend(text,id);
});
$(mainHolder).click(function(){
    $(inputBox).focus();
});

$(".added").live("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).addClass("added-hover");
});
$(".added").live("mouseout",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("added-hover");
    $(this).addClass("added");
});
$(".added").live("click",function(){
    $(mainHolder).find(".selected-friend").removeClass("selected-friend");
    $(this).addClass("selected-friend");
    $(this).find("#rmv_tag").css("color","white");
});
function addFriend(text,id) {
    if(text && ids.length < 5)
    {

        if($(mainHolder).find("div").attr("class") != "added"){
            $("<div class='alert added' class='lists' value='"+id+"'>"+text+"<span id='rmv_tag'>x</span><input type='hidden' class='added_ids[]' name='added_ids[]' value="+id+" /></div>").insertBefore( mainHolder );

        }
        else{
            $("<div class='added' class='lists' value='"+id+"'>"+text+"<span id='close'>x</span></div>").insertAfter($(inputBox).prev());
        }
        // hide list
        $(".list").css("display","none");
        // clear textbox 
        $(inputBox).val("").focus();
        // insert selected id to array
        ids.push(id);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("maximum number of users are already tagged");
        $(inputBox).val("").focus();
        $(inputBox).replaceWith("<span class='text-muted' style='color:#555;font-size:11px;'> Max 5 can be tagged </span>");
    }

}
```

The problem is for the first form I am getting the suggestions but for the second one it's not working.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two elements with the same ID. So when you refer to `$("#selected_ids")` the browser/JavaScript will just effect the first one.

You need to give the two elements different IDs, and in your JavaScript, refer to which one (preferably by passing it as a parameter to a function so you don't just duplicate your code.)

Comment: @user2131695 Hello, I found you had a same problem ... can you please verify my script..